# How to make unicorn run a Rails 3.0 app under a path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, unicorn

I'm migrating from Passenger to Unicorn, and with Passenger I used to run my Rails 3.0 app with the RailsBaseURI option to prefix all URLs with '/blah' for example.

When running the same app under Unicorn, I pass '--path /blah' to unicorn_rails, but the server still serves things as http://server:3000/etc/etc, instead of http://server:3000/blah/etc/etc - I see some assets being requested via /blah/ (like JS files, and so on), but the various links still do not have '/blah/' before them.

So - to summarise - how to I get Unicorn to mount my app under /blah, so that all requests work with '/blah' prepended to the path and all links and assets are created with '/blah/' prepended to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've discovered:

To get a Rails app to serve asset and link URLs, you have to set an environment variable before it starts:

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = '/prefix'
```

Then, as @d11wtq said, to get the Rack-compatible server (in this case, Unicorn) to actually serve the app under a prefix, you have to, in your config.ru file, instead of the usual run line, do the following:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new(
  ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] => Rails.application
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe putting something like this in your config.ru should do it:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

run Rack::URLMap.new(
  "/blah" => Rails.application
)
```

*untested*

Comment: Hmm...... I don't want a different config for development (where nobody currently uses the prefix) and deployed... but I guess I can make a separate config.ru for Unicorn to use.  I'll try it immediately, thanks.

Comment: Hmm.... sending unicorn_rails a --path flag causes assets to be linked as /blah/etc/etc, but other links and the request itself is still served via /.  Your solution does the opposite - links and the app itself are now served from /blah, but the assets are still being served from /.  So I did both - and it worked!  I'd still like a more elegant way if anyone has one - something that does both in one go, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: This solution probably won't work with static assets served directly by your front-end.

Answer (score 1):

The easy and reliable solution is to set the prefix in your front-end setup.

With passenger+nginx for example, you could use something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.phusion.nl;
    root /websites/phusion;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_base_uri /prefix;
}
```

Nothing to change in the source code, one line setup.

---

But you said you're using `unicorn`, which front-end are you using ?

Using nginx is should be possible with something like this:

```
location /prefix {
    rewrite           ^/prefix/(.*)  /$1      break;
    proxy_pass        http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work because the links that get generated without the prefix I want.  In other words, the links won't have /prefix/ prepended to them, thus not working.  I need the app to generate links with the /prefix/ as well.