# How: Multiple Rails apps per VHost - Migrate from Passenger RailsBaseURI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rack, unicorn

I'm migrating from apache/passenger to nginx/unicorn. I've successfully loaded nginix and hosting multiple sites with unicorn, but only one per domain.

In Passenger, one could host multiple rails apps under a single domain, via subfolders, and continue to host a single html file under root.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.2>
    ServerName preview.site.com
    ServerAlias preview.site.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/com.site.preview

    <Directory /var/www/com.site.preview>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /app-one
    RailsBaseURI /app-two
    RailsBaseURI /app-three

</VirtualHost>
```

so going to

```
http://preview.site.com
```

would give me a directory. going to :

```
http://preview.site.com/app-one
http://preview.site.com/app-two
http://preview.site.com/app-three
```

would instead run each application under that sub folder. is there a away I can still do this in nginx/unicorn?

A similar question was asked on [How to make unicorn run a Rails 3.0 app under a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386305/how-to-make-unicorn-run-a-rails-3-0-app-under-a-path), but only provided part of the answer.

Comment: This is not an nginx configuration.. looks like apache2.

Comment: ? That's because, that's exactly what I'm asking?! ..."I'm migrating from apache/passenger to nginx/unicorn."...

Comment: Sorry, this being a month old, I can't for the life of me remember what went through my head when I posted that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is define `locations` inside your nginx configuration. The `server` block defines the nginx application on which port it is running, and to which URL it listens. Inside that block, add the following:

```
location /app-one/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

location /app-two/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}

location /app-three/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

This assumes the following things:

- your apps run on the same box as nginx
- your apps run on the three mentioned ports: 3000, 4000, 5000

This is approach is a reverse-proxy, one of the most common uses for Nginx.